# Converting to VS 2017 .csproj format with PackageReference

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, .net-core, nuget, csproj

I have a legacy solution which I've been gradually upgrading and now want to upgrade the .csproj and .vbproj files to the new 2017 format with PackageReference rather than the packages.config.

The overall solution has around 60+ projects so migrating by hand would be VERY painful. I've been searching for a utility to automate the process without success. Does anyone know of any scripts out there for doing this?

I've tried using [NuGet PackageReference Upgrader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CloudNimble.NuGetPackageReferenceUpgrader) but id doesn't work. I get the following error in my output window

```
24/05/2018 8:37:22 AM: Update failed. Exceptions:
24/05/2018 8:37:22 AM: Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at CloudNimble.PackageReferenceUpgrader.NuGetUpgraderPackage.<>c__DisplayClass9_1.<UpgradePackagesConfig>b__12(XElement c) in C:\projects\packagereferenceupgrader\src\CloudNimble.PackageReferenceUpgrader\NuGetUpgraderPackage.cs:line 187
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass6_0`1.<CombinePredicates>b__0(TSource x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at CloudNimble.PackageReferenceUpgrader.NuGetUpgraderPackage.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<UpgradePackagesConfig>b__1(Int32 i) in C:\projects\packagereferenceupgrader\src\CloudNimble.PackageReferenceUpgrader\NuGetUpgraderPackage.cs:line 187
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<ForWorker>b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object )
24/05/2018 8:37:43 AM: Backup created for D:\workspace\e5tfs\dataract461\e5 Releases\Dev\e5 Foundation\e5 Legacy\Source\SharedAssemblies\Repository\packages.config.
24/05/2018 8:37:43 AM: Update failed. Exceptions:
24/05/2018 8:37:43 AM: Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at CloudNimble.PackageReferenceUpgrader.NuGetUpgraderPackage.<>c__DisplayClass9_1.<UpgradePackagesConfig>b__12(XElement c) in C:\projects\packagereferenceupgrader\src\CloudNimble.PackageReferenceUpgrader\NuGetUpgraderPackage.cs:line 187
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass6_0`1.<CombinePredicates>b__0(TSource x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at CloudNimble.PackageReferenceUpgrader.NuGetUpgraderPackage.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<UpgradePackagesConfig>b__1(Int32 i) in C:\projects\packagereferenceupgrader\src\CloudNimble.PackageReferenceUpgrader\NuGetUpgraderPackage.cs:line 187
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<ForWorker>b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object )
```

Comment: Have you used visual studios own migrator? See [Migrating from package.config to PackageReference format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference)

Answer (score 0):

> Converting to VS 2017 .csproj format with PackageReference

I have created a simple sample with `packages.config`, I can migrate it to `PackageReference` via the tool NuGet PackageReference Upgrader. It is difficult to figure out the reason why you get that error based on the error log.

You can contact the owner of that extension by [Q & A](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CloudNimble.NuGetPackageReferenceUpgrader#qna), If you are interested in.

To accomplish migrate `Packages.config` to `PackageReference`, you can download the **Visual Studio Version 15.7 Preview 3**, which supports migrating a project from the `packages.config` management format to the `PackageReference` format. Check the Visual Studio Blog: [Visual Studio 2017 version 15.7 Preview 3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/04/09/visual-studio-2017-version-15-7-preview-3/) for some more details.